# Oracle View force not null constraint

Tags: database, oracle, view, constraints

Is there a way to force not null constraint for columns in oracle view. Oracle takes constraint for views from underlying source table. But im using some functions on the column which makes the view constraint as null. I know the data from the column will be not null. Is there a way to force it? can you please help.

```
create table a (col_1 date not null);

desc a;

Name  Null     Type 
----- -------- ---- 
COL_1 NOT NULL DATE 


CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW V1 
as select col_1+1 col_1 from a;

desc v1;

Name  Null Type 
----- ---- ---- 
COL_1      DATE
```

Above is the example where the constraint changes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. From [https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/.../clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180):

> > View Constraints
> >
> > Oracle Database does not enforce view constraints. However, you can enforce constraints on views through constraints on base tables.
> >
> > You can specify only unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints on views, and they are supported only in DISABLE NOVALIDATE mode. You cannot define view constraints on attributes of an object column.